# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.setNewText(WebViewClassic.java:587)

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I am getting bug reports from users for months for this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.setNewText(WebViewClassic.java:587)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.setComposingText(WebViewClassic.java:327)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.commitText(WebViewClassic.java:343)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know it's a webview bug but, has anyone been able to fix it?

It only happens on Android 4.2 (97,7%) and Android 4.1 (2,3%)

Thanks

Comment: Have you found any fix yet?

Comment: No, I think there is no fix possible.

Answer (score 1):

Only by moving to a new version of Android that has better WebView support.

Android 2.3 and earlier have notoriously buggy implementation of WebView.

Comment: But it only happens to me on Android 4.2 (97,7%) and Android 4.1 (2,3%)

Comment: Then you should have stated that in your question.

Comment: There is nothing practical that you can do about this. If it is not causing many error I wouldn't worry about it.